# Find an object in array of objects using underscore.js

Tags: javascript, search, underscore.js

I have the following structure

```
var myArr = [ {Code: 'UY', Name: "testdfdgf"}];
```

I need to pull up an object out of this array where Code='UY'.

What would the proper way to do it using _underscore.js? (I don't want to traverse through the array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from underscorejs.org

> findWhere_.findWhere(list, properties)  Looks through the list and
>   returns the first value that matches all of the key-value pairs listed
>   in properties.
>
> If no match is found, or if list is empty, undefined will be returned.
>
> _.findWhere(publicServicePulitzers, {newsroom: "The New York Times"});
>   => {year: 1918, newsroom: "The New York Times",   reason: "For its public service in publishing in full so many official reports,
>   documents and speeches by European statesmen relating to the progress
>   and   conduct of the war."}

So essentially:

```
var codeUY = _.findWhere(myArr, {Code: 'UY'});
```

Underscore will traverse your array to find this, I don't think you can get around it, this should stop at the first match;

Comment: The main downside of findWhere is that it's limited to one dimension / single-depth;  `_.findWhere(myArr, { property: { nested: true } });` will not work, you'll need regular `_.find` or `_.filter` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) function if you want multiple objects with the Code: UY, or the [find](http://underscorejs.org/#find) function to get the first object.